# Possible template solution

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

The argument to the function is an id for a specific type. The function will encode the value supplied in `T` to the value of the type that the tag corresponds to, so I would like to accomplish the following. Is there any neat template trick to get this working?

```
template<int tag_id>
struct tag_traits;

template<>
struct tag_traits<1>
{
    typedef char type;
};

template<>
struct tag_traits<2>
{
    typedef int type;
};

template<>
struct tag_traits<3>
{
    typedef double type;
};

class test {
public:
    test()
    {}

    template <typename T>
    void add_field(int tag, T value)
    {
        using t = typename tag_traits<tag>::type;
        // more...
    }      
};

int main()
{
   test t;
   t.add_field(1, "");
   t.add_field(2, "");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does anything stop you from using `t.add_field<1>("");` in place of `t.add_field(1, "");` ?

Comment: That is not possible, since the tag is not known at compile time.

Comment: You need template arguments at compile time, while the argument for add_field is given at run time. Try explaining what the purpose is? There might be a more suitable solution.

Comment: @Taus I have updated my question, I hope that explains the purpose a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template arguments must be known at compile time. If you can change your function to take `tag` as a template parameter, it will work:

```
template <int tag, typename T>
void add_field(T value)
{
    using t = typename tag_traits<tag>::type;
    // more...
}

// ...

int main()
{
   test t;
   t.add_field<1>("");
   t.add_field<2>("");
}
```

If that is not an option, you'll need a `switch` or similar construct:

```
template <typename T>
void add_field(int tag, T value)
{
  switch (tag) {
    case 1:
    {
      using t = typename tag_traits<1>::type;
      // more...
      break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
      using t = typename tag_traits<2>::type;
      // more...
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that *all* the cases must be syntactically and semantically valid for *all* values of `T`. If that is not an option either, heavy template machinery with a helper trait is needed:

```
template <int tag, class T>
struct is_acceptable : std::false_type
{};

template <int tag>
struct is_acceptable<tag, typename tag_traits<tag>::type> : std::true_type
{};

// Add any other specialisations as applicable

// ...
template <typename T>
void add_field(int tag, T value)
{
  switch (tag) {
    case 1:
    {
      add_field_helper<1, T>::call(value);
      break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
      add_field_helper<2, T>::call(value);
      break;
    }
  }
}

template <int tag, class T, bool acceptable = is_acceptable<tag, T>::value>
struct add_field_helper
{
  static void call(T) {}
};

template <int tag, class T>
struct add_field_helper<tag, T, true>
{
  static void call(T value)
  {
    using t = typename tag_traits<tag>::type;
    // more...
  }
};
```

The empty `call` for the `false` value of `is_acceptable` exists only to prevent compilation errors from incorrect instantiations. Assuming you never call `add_field` with an invalid `tag`-`T` combination, it will never actually be called at runtime.

---

If there are too many tags to practically list them by hand, you could use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to generate them. For valid tag values `0` ... `MAX_TAG - 1`, the following could be used:

```
#define ONE_CASE(z, tag, unused) \
  case tag: add_field_helper<tag, T>::call(value);  break;

template <typename T>
void add_field(int tag, T value)
{
  switch (tag) {
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(MAX_TAG, ONE_CASE, %%)
  }
}
```

I am not using the data parameter normally passed into the macro, which I normally signify by using the syntactic nonsense `%%`. You can pass and use anything there, if you prefer.

If Boost.Preprocessor is too much dark magic for you, you could also use template recursion:

```
template <class T>
void add_field(int tag, T value)
{
  add_field_dispatcher<0, T>::call(tag, value);
}

template <int one_tag, class T>
struct add_field_dispatcher
{
  static void call(int tag, T value)
  {
    if (tag == one_tag) add_field_helper<one_tag, T>::call(value);
    else add_field_dispatcher<one_tag + 1, T>::call(tag, value);
  }
};

template <class T>
struct add_field_dispatcher<MAX_TAG, T>
{
  static void call(int tag, T value)
  {
    // Called with unsupported tag
  }
};
```

Comment: Since there might be more than a hundred tag id´s, the 'switch' solution does not feel like an option.

Comment: @KaptenMugg I've added two options for generating the `switch` (or a similar construct) automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
void add_field(int tag, T value)
{
    using t = typename tag_traits<tag>::type;
    // more...
}
```

The argument for the `tag_traits<tag>` is required to be a compile time constant, in this case it is not. Adding a `const` would not solve the situation either.

A solution would be to move `tag` up to be a template argument.

```
template <int tag, typename T>
void add_field(T value)
{
    using t = typename tag_traits<tag>::type;
    // more...
}
```

Another solution, albeit a little more intricate would be to use a tag dispatching technique - but again, the "dispatch" would be a compile time calculation.

*If the requirement is to get a runtime type, then templates may not be the answer at all, since templates are bound to compile time code generation. In this case, a variant and some form of visitation or more traditional polymorphism may more appropriate.*

Comment: *"constexpr may be useful in this case."*, how is `constexpr` useful here?

Comment: `constexpr` is not useful, I forgot it can't be use on a parameter.

Comment: This is not a solution, since the tag is not known at compile time.

Comment: @KaptenMugg. Given the question *Is there any neat tmp trick to get this working?* - then no, there is no simple trick here. The visitation or polymorphism would be the appropriate solution. You can use templates in these solutions, but there will have to be a runtime calculation on which one to use.

Comment: @KaptenMugg. You mention in several of the comments etc. the size and volume being an issue. I think a higher level design change may be more appropriate and forgiving for future additions and modifications to the code.